# Using DOM (getElementsByTagName) to get "content" meta tag

Tags: php, html, dom, getelementsbytagname

Is it possible to get meta tags content using DOM (getElementsByTagName) for example

This the meta tag that i'm tring to get the content from.

```
<span class="nobr">
    <a href="/title/tt1981115/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_inf " title="See all release dates"> 
        8 November 2013
        <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2013-11-08">
        (USA)
    </a>            
</span>
```

And this is how i'm tring to get the meta content.

```
$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for($i=0; $i <$metas-> length; $i++){
    $itemprop = $metas->item($i)->getAttribute("itemprop");
    if ($itemprop == "datePublished"){
        if ($metas->item($i)->textContent!=''){
            $res['published'] = $metas->item($i)->textContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why won't it get the content?

Comment: What is the content you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: The Published Date (2013-11-08) every page has a different date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need value of content attribute?

```
$metas = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
for($i=0; $i <$metas-> length; $i++){
    $itemprop = $metas->item($i)->getAttribute("itemprop");
    $content = $metas->item($i)->getAttribute("content");
    if ($itemprop == "datePublished" && $content !== ''){
        $res['published'] = $content;
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

Be careful, this code valid for the html example that shows in question. Just you can see direction of your code

Comment: As stated in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666053/using-dom-getelementsbytagname-to-get-content-meta-tag#comment29205295_19666053), the OP is trying to get the published date, not the `content` attribute.

Comment: Published date and content have the same value or I missed something?